# volume of the intersection of the cone and the sphere

Tags: volume, multiple-integral

Find the volume of the portion of the unit sphere which lies inside the right circular cone having its vertex at the origin and making an angle $w$ with the positive z-axis.

Please help me with the sum. I understood that the area would look somewhat like an ice cream cone but how to use triple integration not understanding.

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This is a sum of the volume of a cone and a sphere cap, see https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.17227 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The volume can be integrated in spherical coordinates as

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\omega \int_0^1 r^2\sin\theta \>dr d\theta d\phi=\frac{2\pi}3(1-\cos\omega)$$